# Kivy vertical and horizontal scrollable ScrollView Label. How to reduce/increase the horizontal Label size?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, scrollview

Here's the code for defining a Kivy ScrollView Label whichi can be scrolled both vertically and horizontally:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

class ScrollablePopup(Popup):
    contentBox = ObjectProperty()
    scrollView = ObjectProperty()


    def scrollToTop(self):
        self.scrollView.scroll_y = 1 # force scrolling to top

    def scrollToBottom(self):
        self.scrollView.scroll_y = 0 # force scrolling to bottom

    def initText(self, text):
        self.contentBox.content.text = text


class ScrollPopup(BoxLayout):
    popup = None

    def openPopup(self):
        self.popup = ScrollablePopup(title="Scrollable popup")
        text = u"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus odio nisi, pellentesque molestie adipiscing vitae, aliquam at tellus.\nFusce quis est ornare erat pulvinar elementum ut sed felis. Donec vel neque mauris. In sit amet nunc sit amet diam dapibus lacinia.\nIn sodales placerat mauris, ut euismod augue laoreet at. Integer in neque non odio fermentum volutpat nec nec nulla.\nDonec et risus non mi viverra posuere. Phasellus cursus augue purus, eget volutpat leo. Phasellus sed dui vitae ipsum mattis facilisis vehicula eu justo.\nQuisque neque dolor, egestas sed venenatis eget, porta id ipsum. Ut faucibus, massa vitae imperdiet rutrum, sem dolor rhoncus magna, non lacinia nulla risus non dui.\nNulla sit amet risus orci. Nunc libero justo, interdum eu pulvinar vel, pulvinar et lectus. Phasellus sed luctus diam. Pellentesque non feugiat dolor.\nCras at dolor velit, gravida congue velit. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam eu nunc dui, quis sagittis dolor. Ut nec dui eget odio pulvinar placerat.\nPellentesque mi metus, tristique et placerat ac, pulvinar vel quam. Nam blandit magna a urna imperdiet molestie. Nullam ut nisi eget enim laoreet sodales sit amet a felis.\n"

        for i in range(0, 4):
            text += "\n\n" + text

        self.popup.initText(text)
        self.popup.open()

class ScrollPopupVertHorzApp(App):
    def build(self): # implicitly looks for a kv file of name kivylistview1111.kv which is
                     # class name without App, in lowercases

        Config.set('graphics', 'width', '400')
        Config.set('graphics', 'height', '500')
        Config.write()

        return ScrollPopup()

    def on_pause(self):
        # Here you can save data if needed
        return True

    def on_resume(self):
        # Here you can check if any data needs replacing (usually nothing)
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScrollPopupVertHorzApp().run()
```

scrollpopupverthorz,kv

```
<ScrollPopup>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    popupButton: popup_button

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        Button:
            id: popup_button
            text: "Open scrollable popup"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: "40dp"
            on_press: root.openPopup()

<ScrollablePopup>:
    id: scr_popup
    auto_dismiss: False
    contentBox: content_box
    scrollView: scroll_view
    padding:10, 10

    BoxLayout:
        id: content_box
        orientation: "vertical"
        content: content_text

        ScrollView:
            id: scroll_view
            effect_cls: "ScrollEffect" # prevents overscrolling
            do_scroll_x: True # enabling horizontal scrolling
            Label:
                id: content_text
                size_hint_x: None # required for horizontal scrolling to work. This
                                  # comment is wrong. See the answer below !
                size_hint_y: None # required for horizontal scrolling to work
                height: self.texture_size[1] # required for vertical scrolling to work
                width: self.texture_size[0]  # Set the Label width to the text width.
                                             # Requnred for horizontal scrolling to work
                line_height: 1.5
                valign: "top"

        Button:
            text: "Scroll to top"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: "40dp"
            on_press: scr_popup.scrollToTop()

        Button:
            text: "Scroll to bottom"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: "40dp"
            on_press: scr_popup.scrollToBottom()

        Button:
            text: "Close"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: "40dp"
            on_press: root.dismiss()
```

My question is: how can I set the Label width to a smaller or bigger value without, respectively, cut part of the text lines, or add spaces to the left of each text line ?

Answer (score 1):

The `size_hint` does not actually need to be `None` for scrolling to work, you just need the final height or width to be bigger than the `ScrollView` height or width. So, you can set `size_hint_x` to anything greater than `1`, and you will still get horizontal scrolling:

```
        Label:
            id: content_text
            size_hint_x: 1.5 # must be greater than 1 for horizontal scrolling
            size_hint_y: None # requnred for vertical scrolling to work
            height: self.texture_size[1] # required for vertical scrolling to work
            text_size: self.width, None
            line_height: 1.5
            valign: "top"
```

The key is setting the `text_size`, so that the text is constrained horizontally.

Note that you can use `size_hint_x: None` and set `width` to some specific value. If that `width` is greater than the `ScrollView` `width`, then you will get horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Usíng a scrollable TextInput instead of a scrollable Label does not solve the problem.

Here's the code.

Python file:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

OWNER = 'OWNER'
CAPITAL_USD = 'CAPITAL USD'
YIELD_USD = 'YIELD USD'
CAPITAL_CHF = 'CAPITAL CHF'
YIELD_CHF = 'YIELD CHF'
CAPITAL_EUR = 'CAPITAL EUR'
YIELD_EUR = 'YIELD EUR'
CAPITAL_DM = 'CAPITAL DM'
YIELD_DM = 'YIELD DM'

class PandasTextInputScrolling(BoxLayout):
    textOutput = ObjectProperty()

    def initTextOutput(self):
        self.textOutput.text = ''
        self.textOutput.text = self.createDataframe()

    def clearAll(self):
        self.textOutput.text = ''


    def createDataframe(self):
        df = pd.DataFrame({OWNER: ['John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'Rob', 'Rob', 'Rob', 'Rob', 'Rob',
                                   'Rob', 'Rob', 'Rob', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Bob',
                                   'Bob', 'Bob'] * 3,
                           CAPITAL_USD: [10000, 5000, 20000, 4000, 3000] * 15,
                           YIELD_USD: [1000, 500, 2000, 400, 300] * 15,
                           CAPITAL_CHF: [10000, 5000, 20000, 4000, 3000] * 15,
                           YIELD_CHF: [1000, 500, 2000, 400, 300] * 15,
                           CAPITAL_EUR: [10000, 5000, 20000, 4000, 3000] * 15,
                           YIELD_EUR: [1000, 500, 2000, 400, 300] * 15,
                           CAPITAL_DM: [10000, 5000, 20000, 4000, 3000] * 15,
                           YIELD_DM: [1000, 500, 2000, 400, 300] * 15})

        # adding OWNER total rows

        dfGroupOwnerTotal = df.groupby([OWNER]).agg({CAPITAL_USD: 'sum',
                                                     YIELD_USD: 'sum',
                                                     CAPITAL_CHF: 'sum',
                                                     YIELD_CHF: 'sum',
                                                     CAPITAL_EUR: 'sum',
                                                     YIELD_EUR: 'sum',
                                                     CAPITAL_DM: 'sum',
                                                     YIELD_DM: 'sum'})
        totalDf = pd.DataFrame(columns=[OWNER,
                                        CAPITAL_USD,
                                        YIELD_USD,
                                        CAPITAL_CHF,
                                        YIELD_CHF,
                                        CAPITAL_EUR,
                                        YIELD_EUR,
                                        CAPITAL_DM,
                                        YIELD_DM])
        currentOwner = df.loc[1, OWNER]
        totalDfIndex = 0

        # deactivating SettingWithCopyWarning caueed by totalRow[OWNER] += ' total'
        pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', None)

        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            if currentOwner == row[OWNER]:
                totalDf = totalDf.append({OWNER: row[OWNER],
                                          CAPITAL_USD: row[CAPITAL_USD],
                                          YIELD_USD: row[YIELD_USD],
                                          CAPITAL_CHF: row[CAPITAL_CHF],
                                          YIELD_CHF: row[YIELD_CHF],
                                          CAPITAL_EUR: row[CAPITAL_EUR],
                                          YIELD_EUR: row[YIELD_EUR],
                                          CAPITAL_DM: row[CAPITAL_DM],
                                          YIELD_DM: row[YIELD_DM]}, ignore_index=True)
            else:
                totalRow = dfGroupOwnerTotal.loc[currentOwner]
                totalDf = totalDf.append(totalRow, ignore_index=True)
                totalDf.iloc[totalDfIndex][OWNER] = currentOwner + ' total'
                totalDfIndex += 1
                totalDf = totalDf.append({OWNER: row[OWNER],
                                          CAPITAL_USD: row[CAPITAL_USD],
                                          YIELD_USD: row[YIELD_USD],
                                          CAPITAL_CHF: row[CAPITAL_CHF],
                                          YIELD_CHF: row[YIELD_CHF],
                                          CAPITAL_EUR: row[CAPITAL_EUR],
                                          YIELD_EUR: row[YIELD_EUR],
                                          CAPITAL_DM: row[CAPITAL_DM],
                                          YIELD_DM: row[YIELD_DM]}, ignore_index=True)
                currentOwner = row[OWNER]
            totalDfIndex += 1

        totalRow = dfGroupOwnerTotal.loc[currentOwner]
        totalDf = totalDf.append(totalRow, ignore_index=True)
        totalDf.iloc[totalDfIndex][OWNER] = currentOwner + ' total'

        return totalDf.to_string()


class PandasTextInputScrollingApp(App):
    def build(self):
        if os.name != 'posix':
            # running app om Windows
            Config.set('graphics', 'width', '400')
            Config.set('graphics', 'height', '300')
            Config.write()

        self.gui = PandasTextInputScrolling()
        self.gui.initTextOutput()

        return self.gui

PandasTextInputScrollingApp().run()
```

KV file:

```
<PandasTextInputScrolling>:
    textOutput: txt_output

    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint_y: 0.9

            ScrollView:
                id: scrlv
                size_hint_y: 0.9
                effect_cls: "ScrollEffect" # prevents overscrolling
                TextInput:
                    id: txt_output
                    readonly: True
                    size_hint_x: 1.5  # any value greater than 1 can be set to enable
                                      # scrolling, with the risk of cutting part of the
                                      # text width !
                    size_hint_y: None # required for horizontal scrolling to work
                    height: self.texture_size[1] # required for vertical scrolling to work
                    line_height: 1.5
                    height: max( (len(self._lines)+1) * self.line_height, scrlv.height)
            Button:
                id: clear_output_Button
                text: 'Clear'
                size_hint_y: 0.1
                on_press: root.clearAll()
            Button:
                id: fill_output_Button
                text: 'Show Pandas data frame'
                size_hint_y: 0.1
                on_press: root.initTextOutput()
```